# Did Biosphere 2 make any discoveries later used on manned space flight?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, research, habitat, science, sustainability

[Biosphere 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2) operated as a closed entity for study of closed ecological systems for stints between 1991 to 1994.  Given that the ISS has been continuously inhabited from 2000 to the present day, it seems like any lessons learned from Biosphere 2 would have been timely and relevant.

Was there even a single discovery or clearly identifiable scientific product that resulted from Biosphere 2 and was later used for the ISS or other manned spaceflight?

Comment: I think the lessons learned is we don't know nearly enough about how to make an independent biosphere.  In fact in 2003 it changed from a closed system to an open system.  Pretty much a big failure in terms of closed space type system.

Comment: Not much ever came from it that could be applied to closed ecosystems, but I found a good updated summary of Biosphere2 for you http://discovermagazine.com/2010/oct/20-life-under-the-bubble#.UkvfALNsdOA

Comment: I don't think it has yet but I think it spawned more interest in closed loop systems with ESA's Project MELiSSA http://www.esa.int/SPECIALS/Melissa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No evidence for identifiable scientific product(s) later used by the ISS and/or other manned spaceflight. However, researchers of biosphere two found the original crew's lowered blood pressure, blood cholesterol, and enhancement of there immune systems to be caused by Roy Walford's low calorie restriction diet (Walford, R., Mock D, Verdery R, MacCallum T, Calorie Restriction in Biosphere 2 Alterations in Physiologic, Hematologic, Hormonal, and Biochemical Parameters in Humans Restricted for a 2-Year Period). Perhaps, this could be interpreted as a model for outer space cuisine for astronauts. Probably not though. Currently, researchers at biosphere two study different biomes and there interactions.